# heroku deployment nodemailer

Tags: heroku, nodemailer

I can deploy my app locally, but not on heroku. I'm using nodemailer and trying to send mail to myself from my website. This is the route:

````
app.post('/contact', function (req, res) {
    let mailOpts, smtpTrans;
    smtpTrans = nodemailer.createTransport({
        servic: 'gmail',
        auth: {
            user: 'randomemail',
            pass: 'password'
        }
    });
    mailOpts = {
        from: req.body.name + ' &lt;' + req.body.email + '&gt;',
        to: 'randomemail',
        subject: 'New message from contact form at your portfolio page',
        text: `${req.body.name} (${req.body.email}) says: \n \n ${req.body.message}`
    };
    smtpTrans.sendMail(mailOpts, function (error, response) {
        if (error) {
            res.render('contact-failure');
        }
        else {
            res.send(response);
        }
    });
});```
````

And this is the error I get when I try to send myself mail from heroku.

```
2018-05-29T06:31:32.280501+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=POST path="/contact" host=desolate-journey-40239.herokuapp.com request_id=4c462f91-9f47-4566-943a-2c5e24d795ac fwd="75.74.137.60" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=89ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
```

NOTE: Some things I've tried going here: https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha and unlocking my account to no avail.

Any response is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed the typo on 'service' and that seems to have fixed my error.